# Символьные массивы.Обратный порядок слов

Tags: c, массивы

Ввожу предложение и на выходе хочу получить обратный порядок слов.
Была идея сделать два массива. Оригинальный массив с предложением рассматривать  с конца и записывать в новый массив ( где уже должен быть обратный порядок слов).
Но с реализацией не вышло.
Потом решил сделать по-другому

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<conio.h>
 #include<string.h>
void main(void) {
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0;
char A[60];
gets_s(A);
puts(A);
l = strlen(A);
while (l>=0) {
    j = j + 1;
    if (A[l] == 32) {
        while (k <= j) {
            printf("%c", A[l + ++k]);

        }
        k = 0; j = 0;
    }

    l--;
}
_getch();
}
```

Просто выводить на экран слова с конца , ориентируясь по пробелу

Comment: related: [Efficiently reverse the order of the words (not characters) in an array of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47402/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот , заработало

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main(void) {
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0, t = 0;
char A[60];
gets_s(A);
puts(A);
l = strlen(A);
while (l>=0) {
    j = j + 1;
    if (A[l] == 32   ) {
        while (k <= j) {
            printf("%c", A[l + k++]);

        }
        k = 0; j = 0;
    }
    l--;

}
while (A[t] != 32)
    t++;
for (j = 0; j < t;j++) {
    printf("%c", A[j]);
}
_getch();
}
```

Додумался все-таки

Answer (score 2):

[Вот так](https://ideone.com/VqRJDc) не устроит?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int iswhite(int c)
{
    return !c || isspace(c) || ispunct(c);
}

void swap(char* a, char * b)
{
    char t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

void reverseWord(char * b, char * e)
{
    while(b < e)
    {
        swap(b++,e--);
    }
}

char * reverse(char * s)
{
    reverseWord(s,s+strlen(s)-1);
    for(char* c = s; *c; ++c)
    {
        if (iswhite(*c)) continue;
        char * b = c;
        while(!iswhite(*c)) ++c;
        reverseWord(b,c-1);
    }
    return s;
}

char s[] = "Привет, это длинное предложение!";

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    puts(reverse(s));
}
```