# Проблема с передачей строчного массива в функцию переворота строки C++

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, функции

пытаюсь сам дойти хотя бы до функции переворота строки, но 
не освоил общение функций с массивами

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
char string_turnover(int n, char s[n]){
    int i;
    char buff;
    for(i=0; i<(n/2); i++){
        buff=s[i];
        s[i]= s[ n-i ];
        s[n-i]= buff;
    }
return s;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    char user_string[500];
    cout << "Введите вашу строку(латиницей): ";
    cin >> user_string;
    int length=strlen(user_string);
    cout << "Длинна строки равна " << length << endl;
    char short_string[length];
    char revolutionary_string[length]= string_turnover(length, short_string);
    cout<< revolutionary_string;
    return 0;
}
```

что не так? qt жалуется на то, что "n" и "s" в функции не объявлены, но используются и на строку

```
char revolutionary_string[length]= string_turnover(length, short_string);
```

пишет

```
/home/petr-55vd/untitled/main.cpp:26: ошибка: array must be initialized
with a brace-enclosed initializer
     char revolutionary_string[length]= string_turnover(length, short_string);
                                                                            ^
```

может попробовать через уазатель( или лучше через ссылку). Если стоит, то как это сделать( как менять элементы массива потом в функции местами)

## **UPDATE**

сделал через динамическое выделение памяти,однако осталась последняя проблема: функция не принимает строку выдавая

```
ошибка: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
strcpy(revolutionary_string,string_reverse(length, user_string));
                                                   ^
```

и указывая на строку

```
strcpy(revolutionary_string,string_reverse(length, user_string));
```

сам код выглядит

```
char string_reverse(int n, char* s){
    int i;
    char buff;
    for(i=0; i<(n/2); i++){
        buff=s[i];
        s[i]= s[ n-i ];
        s[n-i]= buff;
    }
return *s;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");

    //ввод пользовательской строки
    char user_string[500];
    cout << "Введите вашу строку(латиницей): ";
    cin >> user_string;
    int length=strlen(user_string);
    cout << "Длина строки равна " << length << endl;

    char *revolutionary_string = new char[length];
    strcpy(revolutionary_string,string_reverse(length, user_string));

    cout << revolutionary_string << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Длина пишется с одним н. Это тоже ошибка.

Comment: тогда создавать динамический массив?

Comment: используйте std::vector

Comment: а что там с длинной?

Comment: про векторы почитаю, спасибо)

Comment: Слово ДЛИНА c 1 н пишется.

Comment: @tilin, можно, но только на стеке, длина может быть неизвестна заранее. `-std=c99`

Comment: Вы правы. Моя ошибка.

Comment: @0andriy а хотя нет. речь шла о с++. А там такой возможности стандартом не предусмотрено. Хотя gcc и clang ее реализуют.

Answer (score 2):

Да вы нарушаете синтаксис языка, только и всего :)

Вместо

```
char string_turnover(int n, char s[n]){
```

пишите

```
char string_turnover(int n, char *s){
```

Ну а вместо

```
char revolutionary_string[length]= string_turnover(length, short_string);
```

поскольку *инициализировать массив* вычисляемым во время выполнения значением нельзя,

```
char revolutionary_string[length];
strcpy(revolutionary_string,string_turnover(length, short_string));
```

Надеюсь, места точно хватит...

Не заметил сразу - так у вас еще и длина вычисляется? Тогда не годится и

```
char revolutionary_string[length];
```

воспользуйтесь или динамическим массивом, или, еще лучше, обычной стандартной строкой `string` - вот ее можете инициализировать сколько угодно :)

**Update**

Только что в другом ответе давал функцию разворота...

```
void reverse(char * b, char * e)
{
    while(b < e)
    {
        char t = *b;
        *b++ = *e;
        *e-- = t;
    }
}
```

И вызывать как `reverse(s,s+strlen(s)-1)`.

Comment: Я бы еще добавил, код s[n-i]= buff; ведет к порче памяти когда i = 0.

Comment: string уже имеет готовый reverse, но вряд ли это зачтут.

Comment: Все-таки e надо декрементировать, если это разворот.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka Да, конечно. Я не копипастил, а руками менял, вот и ошибся. Там - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/729008/195342 - немного по-другому писано.

Answer (score 1):

Возможный вариант:

```
char* string_turnover(int n, char* s)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n/2; ++i)
        std::swap(s[i], s[n-1-i]);
    return s;
}
```

Только помните, что n должно соответствовать количеству символов **без** завершающего нуля.

Comment: задача- переворот без сторонних библиотек (векторы- сторонняя)

Comment: А где вы у меня увидели вектор? И даже если бы я использовал векторы, это самая что ни на есть стандартная библиотека, а не сторонняя.

Comment: swap- функция векторов
ее нельзя использовать, не подключив <vector>

Comment: swap не имеет никакого отношения к векторам. Она просто переставляет свои аргументы местами. Если запрещено ее использовать, сделайте перестановку ручками - тем более в вашем коде такая перестановка есть.

Answer (score 1):

Мой вариант

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
#include <cstring>
#include <conio.h>



using namespace std;
void string_turnover(int n, char *s){
    int i;

    char buff;
    for(i=0; i<(n/2); i++){
        buff=s[i];
        s[i]= s[ n-i-1 ];
        s[n-i-1]= buff;
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    char user_string[500];
    cout << "Введите вашу строку(латиницей): ";
    cin >> user_string;
    int length=strlen(user_string);
    cout << "Длина строки равна " << length << endl;
    char* short_string=new char[length];
    strcpy(short_string,user_string);

    string_turnover(length, short_string);

    cout<< short_string;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: здесь функция ничего не возвращает

Comment: @КурняковПетр зачем возвращать, если переданный параметр реверсируется.

Comment: понял, спасибо)